# Unregister $scope.$on handler manually

Tags: angularjs

We subscribe to broadcast events in our controller constructor like this:

```
var unsubscribe = $scope.$on("event-name", function() { // handle it });
```

And when controller gets destroyed we unsubscribe like this to prevent memory leak

```
$scope.$on("$destroy", function() {
  unsubscribe();
  unsubscribe = null;
});
```

But somewhere I read that calling this is not necessary as when controller is destroyed subscribed handlers are destroyed automatically (if they are declared on controller's scope - which in this case are).

Is unsubscribing them manually really necessary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically you don't need to unsubscribe to `$scope.$on` events as the `$scope` is destroy along with the event listeners anyway. (and you don't need to set the variable to null either).

It's different from `$rootScope.$on` listeners as the `$rootScope` is not destroyed.

That being said, it is considered bad practice to listen to events using `$scope.$on` or create events inside the $scope.

1. You expose yourself to name conflicts
2. You're obfuscating your code by adding events that will be hard to
   find when the code gets bigger
3. These events make sense for application-wise events (login, logout,
   notification...etc.) but not for small isolated events
   ("received-product-list")
4. Refactor your code so that $scope events are replaced with promises.

Comment: Thanks for explanation. We use this to listen to broadcasted events that are coming from 3rd party directive we are using. For our code we do not use this approach.